# Disable browser prefixes in SASS Compass?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, compass

Is there a way of disabling all of the browser prefixes that Compass adds?

Example;

```
.heartbeat {
  @include animation(heartbeat 0.5s linear infinite);
}
```

Generates this:

```
.heartbeat {
    -moz-animation    : heartbeat .5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation : heartbeat .5s linear infinite;
    animation         : heartbeat .5s linear infinite
}
```

But all I want is this:

```
.heartbeat {
    animation         : heartbeat .5s linear infinite
}
```

Yes, I could simply replace

```
.heartbeat {
  @include animation(heartbeat 0.5s linear infinite);
}
```

with

```
.heartbeat {
  animation(heartbeat 0.5s linear infinite);
}
```

But I would prefer not to modify the SASS code.

Comment: You can [tune some variables](http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/tuning-vendor-prefixes/), but why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I wanted to use GULP Autoprefixer instead of having to use the Compass approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing:

```
compass interactive
browsers()
```

Got all supported browser:

```
("android", "android-chrome", "android-firefox", "blackberry", "chrome", "firefox", "ie", "ie-mobile", "ios-safari", "opera", "opera-mini", "opera-mobile", "safari")
```

And finally adding this to a sass-file:

```
$supported-browsers: reject(browsers(), "android", "android-chrome", "android-firefox", "blackberry", "chrome", "firefox", "ie", "ie-mobile", "ios-safari", "opera", "opera-mini", "opera-mobile", "safari");
```

Comment: Strange it's not possible to just go the other way around and white-list that one browser I want to support.